# 1000Base-T Server NIC speed slows down to 100Base-T when sending data to a 100Base-T device

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I am conducting experiments to explore how data transmission is being influenced by the network speeds of the receivers. Here is my setup,

I have an Ubuntu server **A** connected to a Gigabit switch with 2 other clients **(B and C)**. All machines have been installed with a gigabit NIC card

While Clients **A B** are operating at 1000mbps, client **C** is configured to run at 100Mbps by ethtool using the following command

> ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full

With this setup, i have attempted to send a 500MB file from **A** to clients **B** and **C** at the same time via SCP.

I have expected the data transmission rate between **A** and **C** to be 100mbps, and **A** and **B** to be 1000mbps.

However in reality, the transmission rate of **A** to both **B** and **C** has been dropped to 100mbps.

My question is: is this behavior to be expected? If so, is there a way to send data from **A** to **B** and **C** concurrently at different network speeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is one of the boundary conditions that some network hardware manufacturers may or may not choose to implement wisely. a lot of it depends on the switch mode, per-port-buffer size, and backplane speed, as well as host metrics like the nic, systembus, and CPU speed.

SCP requires encryption/decryption so the host system bus, Nic bus, and CPU capacity are all factors. if the recieving pc can't keep up with the flow, it sends source-quench flow control messages to the switch, which slows down output to that port, which may cause the switch buffers to fill up, and may result in the switch relaying source-quench messages to the sending system, instructing it to slow down. source quench occurs at layer 2, so there is little or no differentiation between the two flows; it has to slow down both of them. the port-buffer for the sending host is likely full as well, meaning that data can only be sent into it at the rate it can be sent on to the slower destination.

in the end, it all depends on the grade of your equipment. if you are connecting rack servers over fiberchannel to a enterprise grade switch, and then into a smaller distribution switch, then I would not expect this problem. if you are using 3 old pc's connected by ratty cat5e to a couple $100 netgear switches, then I would completely expect it.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed clarification of the underlying aspects of the network that could affect network transmission speed. And yes, my setup has been very accurately described in the latter example

Comment: On another note, with regards to the source-quench flow control on the sending system, does it result in just the limitation of bandwidth between the sender and recipient, or does it limit the bandwidth of the sender's link in general? You did mention that it occurs at layer 2 hand hence has no differentiation between the two flows... i suppose that means that means that it limits the bandwidth of the sender's link and all other traffic regardless of its destination has to adhere to the limit?

Comment: it all depends on Server A's switch port buffer. if it fills up, then it can't release data for the faster recipient faster than it can to the slower. if this buffer doesn't fill, and the switch has sufficient capacity, it would attempt to deliver to the faster host at its own speed. Source-quench does attempt to be destination specific, but when the sender has only one connection to the switch, and the receiving switch ports rx buffer is full, then there is little it can do.